# How can I change position UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, position

I have a `UITabBar` on the bottom of screen. After click on `UITextField` shows `UIDatePicker`, but my problem is that Picker cover my TabBar. Is possible to change Picker position for, in example, 100px from bottom?

Comment: It’s no different than if you showed a normal keyboard. The tab bar will be covered. Provide a way to dismiss the picker (or keyboard).

Comment: Let's try other way. I have `TabBar` in `ViewController`, I have also `UILabel` which shows `UIPickerView` after click on it, but my PickerView shows above `TabBar`. Is it possible to hide this bar?